# The service does not receive the e-mail address as an input

Tags: ios, swift, api, swiftui

I'm trying to get data from API with SwiftUI but I'm failing. I created Rest Api on Eclipse and I'm trying to get username and password from url http://localhost... and process it. However, when I press the login button in the ios app, it says SELECT count(1) FROM USER where EMAIL=NULL in the console in Eclipse.

```
    func Login(password: String, username: String){
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/dentistodayapis10062022/login") else {
        return
    }
    
    let body : [String : String] = ["password": password, "username": username]
    
    guard let finalBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(body) else {
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = finalBody
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        
//            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
//                print("No data response")
//
//                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                    self.isApiReachable = false
//                }
//                return
//
//            }
        
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {return}
        // decode data
        let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Json4Swift_Base.self, from: data)
        if let result = result {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.anamodel = result
                self.isCorrect = true
                withAnimation{
                    self.log_Status = true
                }
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isCorrect = false
                print("Invalid response from web services!")
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

[image: POSTMAN]

```
Button {
                    if loginData.registerUser{
                        loginData.Register()
                    }
                    else{
                        loginData.Login(password: loginData.password, username: loginData.email)
                    }
                } label: {
                    
                    Text("Login")
                        .font(.custom(customFont, size: 17).bold())
                        .padding(.vertical,20)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color("Purple"))
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.07), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
                }
```

Comment: You are saying that you'll send ``x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters, but in fact your send JSON... That doesn't make sense... And print also `error`, `String(data: data, encoding:.utf8)` and `response`, it might give info on why it failed...

Comment: @larme When I look at Postman, Content-type says application/x-www-form-urlencoded. What should I do

Comment: Try with `request.httpBody = Data("username=\(username)&password=\(password)".utf8)`?